# MySQL SET Syntax on Raw in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

Can I use the MySql SET Type to create a RawQuerySet on Django, for example:

```
sql = """SET @some_variable = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Model);
         SET @other_variable = (SELECT COUNT (name) FROM Model);
         SELECT @some_variable, @other_variable"""
```

And then

```
var = Model.objects.raw(sql)
print var
print len(list(var))
```

If anyone can clarify this doubt, appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because response must be mappable to your model.

Checkout https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/